# How to setup custom event tracking with new Google Analytics (GA4) on the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I would like to send event data to Google analytics 4 to track conversions on my web app. I found this article: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag#send_an_event

First I made a custom event that looks like this:
[image: Custom event]

I created an `api secret` and included my `measurement_id`.

I then tried sending data to GA4 with the example in the article:

```
  const measurement_id = `G-XXXXXXXXX`;
  const api_secret = `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`;

  await fetch(
    `https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${measurement_id}&api_secret=${api_secret}`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "User-Agent":
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        client_id: "123.123333",
        events: [
          {
            name: "conversion",
            params: { succes: true },
          },
        ],
      }),
    }
  );
```

I cannot get this to work. Does anyone have experience with this or done something similar that can shine some light on what is going wrong here?

Comment: Please define **I cannot get this to work.**  what doesn't work?

Comment: Before I began with this I knew it could take some time for a post request to be visible in de GA4 dashboard, but it ended up taking a whole day. The next day all the post requests that I did were measured in the dashboard. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes between 34 - 48 hours for data to be shown in the standard reports on google analytics web app.  This is due to data processing latency.

If its a new google analytics account it can take up to 72 hours for it to begin displaying data.

The best way to test your requests its to look at the real-time report.  it will show if its getting hits almost instantly.

Answer (score 0):

**To create a Google Analytics 4 Event tag:**

> 1. Click Tags > New.
> 2. Click Tag Configuration.
> 3. Select Google Analytics: GA4 Event.
> 4. For Configuration Tag, select the Configuration Tag you created earlier.
> 5. For Event Name, specify the name of the event. Use the recommended event names for best results.
> 6. Optional: Enter Event Parameters. Use recommended event parameter names for best results.
>
>    1. Click Add Row.
>    2. Enter a Parameter Name.
>    3. Enter a Value.
> 7. Repeat until all desired parameters have been added.    Optional: Add any custom user properties that you'd like to configure in User
>    Properties. Note: Analytics automatically logs some user properties.
>    You can set up to 25 additional user properties per Google Analytics 4
>    property.
> 8. Click Triggering and select appropriate events that would cause the tag to fire.
> 9. Save the tag configuration and publish your container.

```
const measurementId = `G-XXXXXXXXXX`;
const apiSecret = `<secret_value>`;

fetch(`https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${measurementId}&api_secret=${apiSecret}`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "client_id": "client_id",
    "events": [{
      "name": "generate_lead",
      "params": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": 99.99
      }
    }]
  })
});
```